# monitor processes in citrix

Tags: windows-server-2003, citrix, strace

Where I work, We've been having trouble with certain applications mysteriously crashing/hanging in citrix; the primary culprits are IE8 and a certain .net-based industry specific app that we use.

I've yet to actually catch either/any of these applications actually freezing up.

What I'd really like is a stack trace leading up to the hang to see if that might yield more information; something that I could run in the background on a few random servers for a day or so and compare with reports from users of freezes / crashes.

I've tried messing around with procmon some, but the issue i've found is that after a couple of hours, I'll end up with many gigabytes of data from each server, even if I only target a couple of apps. (could be user error on my part though).

Does anyone have experience with this kind of thing, or have any advice on a better way to go about collecting this sort of information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're after [adplus](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350).  It gives you exactly what you're after.

Its included in the Windows dev tools (debugging tools).  You run it as, something like,

```
adplus -p <PID> -crash (or -hang) -o <output directory>
```

Will collect a number of things on activation including,

- Memory dump
- Stack trace